# need single header file for boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Boost::shared_ptr is really great. But using it you need lots of header file. Is thare any single header file available that will provide shared_ptr functionality?

somewhat urgent.

Comment: Can you use `std::tr1::shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc -E boost/shared_ptr.hpp -o my_shared_ptr.hpp`

Using the preprocessor, you generate a single header containing everything you need.

Comment: This may not be safe. It'll fixate many macros which may be configuration or system dependent. That is, as soon as a new version is installed or you move OS's your generated header may be broken.

Comment: @edA: true, I would use it more as a compilation speed-up (and thus generate it as part of the build) than as a delivered header. But for one shot projects (homework/prototype) it's easier and works great.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to avoid having all the boost header files although you use shared_ptr only, you can extract the shared_ptr with BCP:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html

It won't give you a single header file, though, but I doubt that this would give you any noticeable advantage.